# Self-referencing Query and Not Equals

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to pull data from a single table called tblTooling where two TlPartNo numbers are equal to different values and the TlToolNo are not equal for these TlPartNo . This is an Access DB and the following statement gets me close, but still gives too much data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   tblTooling.TlToolNo, 
   tblTooling.TlPartNo, 
   tblTooling.TlOP, 
   tblTooling.TlQuantity
FROM tblTooling, tblTooling AS tblTooling_1
WHERE (((tblTooling.TlToolNo)<>tblTooling_1.TlToolNo) 
 AND ((tblTooling.TlPartNo)="10290722") 
 AND ((tblTooling_1.TlPartNo)="10295379"));
```

The included image has the tblTooling structure and Data. Plus the expected results from the query.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want exclude a *ToolNo* value when it occurs with both *PartNo* values. In that case you could group intermediate results by *ToolNo*, and see whether in such a group there is only one *PartNo* present (with `having`). In that case keep that record, and in the outer query, get the two other columns added to it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            tblTooling.TlToolNo, 
            tblTooling.TlPartNo, 
            tblTooling.TlOP, 
            tblTooling.TlQuantity
FROM        tblTooling
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT    TlToolNo,
                      Min(TlPartNo) AS MinTlPartNo,
                      Max(TlPartNo) AS MaxTlPartNo
            FROM      tblTooling
            WHERE     TlPartNo IN ("10290722", "10295379")
            GROUP BY  TlToolNo
            HAVING    Min(TlPartNo) = Max(TlPartNo)
           ) AS grp
        ON  grp.TlToolNo = tblTooling.TlToolNo
       AND  grp.MinTlPartNo = tblTooling.TlPartNo
```

Note that for your sample data this will return 4 rows:

```
TlToolNo  | TlPartNo | TlOP | TlQuantity
----------+----------+------+-----------
T00012362 | 10290722 | OP10 | 2
T00012456 | 10290722 | OP10 | 1
T00013456 | 10290722 | OP20 | 1
T00014348 | 10295379 | OP20 | 1
```

Comment: Getting an missing operator error message on "HAVING  Count(Distinct TlPartNo) = 1". I have not been able to fix the error.

Comment: It turns out MS Access does not support that clause, although it is valid according to the SQL standard. But you can have the same output with another variant of `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tblTooling as t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblTooling as t2
                  where t2.TlPartNo in ("10290722", "10295379") and
                        t2.TlToolNo = t.TlToolNo and
                        t2.tiid <> t.tiid
                 ) and
      t.TlPartNo in ("10290722", "10295379");
```

This saves on the `select distinct`, which should be a performance boost.

Comment: This statement gives no data at all, even after trying many adjustments.

Comment: @stevet . . . I don't see why it wouldn't work.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?